# Passing a pandas dataframe object into a function

Tags: python, function, pandas, dataframe

I have dataframe objects that I would like to to pass into a function.

```
x = pd.Dataframe()

def function(z):
    "code"
    return result

result = function(x)
```

I'm new to python, can someone please steer me in the right direction.

Comment: Your question makes zero sense, there's no explanation of where you're stuck or what you expect your function to do

Comment: Thanks for your help EdChum, really appreciated. I have a dataframe object = x that I want to pass to a function <def function(z)> so I can manipulate and format my dataframe. Again I'm new to python and just wanted some feedback on how I would do this.

Answer (score 8):

Below I am showing a simple function that would have the input parameter as a DataFrame object, and it would check if one of the columns has the String "Some", if so, it returns the Boolean results.

Check if this helps.

```
x = pd.DataFrame([[1,'Some Text'],[2,'New Text']],columns=('SINO','String_Column'))

def function(z):
    l_local_df = z['String_Column'].str.contains('Some')
    return l_local_df

result = function(x)
print result
```

Comment: thank you. Wasn't sure if it was possible since I was getting an error.